# Abp-Identity-permission angular UI shows uuid/guid on header and label of policy at version 2.9

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, abp

This question has two parts:

Firstly, following logic works when I assign a specific policy to a specific user but on the front-end, when the admin-user navigates through Identity Management and opens the user permissions popup window, it shows the GUID to header and policy label.

```
public override void Define(IPermissionDefinitionContext context)
    {
        var myGroup = context.AddGroup(
            "ABC",
            LocalizableString.Create<EazyCateringResource>("Permission:ABC"),
            MultiTenancySides.Tenant);
  
        var staff = 
        myGroup.AddPermission(
            Statics.Staff,
            LocalizableString.Create<EazyCateringResource>("Permission:ABC_Staff"),
            multiTenancySide: MultiTenancySides.Tenant);
        
        staff.AddChild("demo_staff",....); 
    }
```

and there is a DataSeed to add default permissions where code looks like:

```
_currentTenant.Change(defualtTenant.Id);
var userId = ...
// assign permission to user
await _permissionManager.SetForUserAsync(userId, "demo.", true)
```

[image: abp-identiy-ui-module-error]

I have tried both **AddPermissions** and **AddChild** but the same issue.

Now, is there any config somewhere to hide those Ids on UI?

Secondly, what is the "AbpIdentity.UserLookup" meant for? why I can't assign it using code during DataSeed for a tenant?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no config to hide the IDs. But you can replace the PermissionManagementComponent with your custom permissions component.

See the [Component Replacement](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Component-Replacement) and [How to Replace PermissionManagementComponent](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Permission-Management-Component-Replacement) documents on ABP documentation.

Comment: this issue also happens in version 3.2. Can you please how to replace top nabvar to be left sidebar ?

Comment: You can replace the ApplicationLayoutComponent with your custom layout component that contain left sidebar instead of top navbar. Please check the [Layout Replacement on ABP documentation](/api/account/send-phone-number-confirmation-token) for ApplicationLayoutComponent replacement.